# How to use PHP and curl to execute a POST call

Tags: php, asp.net, web-services, curl

I am trying to use curl with PHP to execute a POST call from PHP but always I get page error

this is my code

```
if($curl = curl_init()){
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://marcelotavarez.com/freeodds.aspx');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "CallbackMethod=GetLines&Parm1=20170110&Parm2=2&Parm3=0&CallbackParmCount=3&__WW EVENTCALLBACK=CustomerCallback&__WWEVENTTARGET=Page&__VIEWSTATE=/wEPDwUKLTQwNjM5NzY1NmRkOa+UqFoVFF+BzUdMUBBH1ahGsWQ=&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=BB49A8FA&");

$out = curl_exec($curl);

echo "===\n $out \n====\n";
$out = str_replace("\"","",$out);
```

}

Using the inspector from Chrome I checked the header that I need to use to do the POST Call and these are:

```
CallbackMethod:GetLines
Parm1:"20170110"
Parm2:2
Parm3:0
CallbackParmCount:3
__WWEVENTCALLBACK:CustomerCallback
__WWEVENTTARGET:Page
__VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwUKLTQwNjM5NzY1NmRkOa+UqFoVFF+BzUdMUBBH1ahGsWQ=
__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR:BB49A8FA
```

Any time that I use this code just I get the error page

Any cluees or any help , pls

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I need to ask you a question where is CallbackMethod=GetLines

`GetLines function` , I think must be in your code to be executed after response back